# Error with shared nothing migration between failover clusters

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to script a system for migrating between Hyper-V failover clusters.

I have configured constrained kerberos delegation etc as per the documentation,

I am:

- Removing the VM from cluster A
- Calling Move-VM in a Powershell instance running with domain credentials, syntax i am using:

  ```
  Move-VM -IncludeStorage -DestinationHost 'clusterB.node1' -name test -DestinationStoragePath 'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2'
  ```

This will fail with the following error:

```
Move-VM : Virtual machine migration operation failed at migration source. 

Security check failed.

Virtual machine migration operation for 'test' failed at migration source

Migration did not succeed. 

User does not have enough rights for 'C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\test.vhdx'.
```

The fault seems to be related to the cluster shared volume.

If I move the .vhdx to the local system drive the migration works using the process mentioned above.

The really maddening thing is if perform the migration from the GUI it also works.

Has anyone got any idea where I am going wrong? I would be very happy to be missing something obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding, "*Calling Move-VM in a Powershell instance running with domain credentials*", as Stuka's answer implies, "domain credentials" isn't very specific. What kind of domain credentials? Do those credentials have the permissions and privileges required?

Answer (score 3):

Use domain administrator (enterprise administrator) for this action. Also, you can try to add domain admin as the local administrator on each cluster nodes for both clusters and try to migrate the VM once again or even add the particular user as the cluster name/nodes owner inside the AD/DC.

Answer (score 0):

This actually ended up being my problem:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2014/10/01/virtual-machine-checkpoint-fails-with-access-denied-when-running-on-a-clustered-shared-volume/

My .vhdx were all on the root of the CSV volume. I don't quite know what Move-Vm is doing when it creates it's checkpoint\snapshot in order to punt the disk contents, but it simply cannot be made to work if them VM is on the root of the CSV.

How i got this working was to look into this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/move-vmstorage?view=win10-ps

... to move the content 'locally' on Cluster A to its own folder structure (without downtime).

I also had to ensure the domain account i was using with constrained delegation had write permissions on the 'Virtual Hard Disk' folder in the folder tree created when using the command above, presumably for the migration process to create its differencing content during the migration...

tl;dr never put anything in root of a clustered shared volume